# Lucene indexing without html css tags java

Tags: java, html, lucene, tags

I am using lucene to index my data using java programming language. But still, when i retrieve the terms that lucene indexed, they appear with tags like html (html is considered as a term not a tag and lucene doesn't remove it).
Is there any code or library for example like English analyzer that can remove the desired html tags?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove html tags before indexing them in Lucene, you might use [PatternReplaceCharFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternReplaceCharFilter.html). It uses a regular expression for the target of replace string.

You could create char filter like this:

```
CharFilter cf = new PatternReplaceCharFilter(Pattern.compile("<[^>]*>"), "", reader);
```

this, will replace all html tags with empty string, so it will be removed.